# Activity does not show title bar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have create demo application in Android Studio with two Activity. In First Activity Show Title Bar in preview as well as in emulator but on second Activity does not show Title Bar in Emulator but it display in preview. I have used API 22 in Android Studio.
Please help me....thanx in advn

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/BaseTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DrawingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/BaseTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

Theme style file like this....

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>

<style name="BaseTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_backgound</item>
</style>
```

I have also try this...
First Activity Work's fine so I have set that in Second Activity as a setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void buttonAction(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

DrawActivity.java

```
public class DrawingActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Comment: what's your parent theme?

Comment: Did you add a theme for activity ?

Comment: yes i have add theme for activity

Comment: which theme you have added?

Comment: Remove android:theme="@style/BaseTheme" from DrawingActivity and then try and use AppTheme at application level

Comment: I have tried this also....@Mahesh Suthar

Comment: can we see the relevant codes of `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`??

Comment: yes..i edit question...@Boss

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing is a bug related to the API 22(5.1) SDK.

Kindly refer the following links for the details on the bug in which the Action Bar is not displayed:

1. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159793
2. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159780

**What you can do for now**

1. Either revert back to API 21 if possible or,
2. Select API 21 in the compile with (render with) option in Android Studio.

Hope this helps.