# Android Studio-Designer does not show as the emulator/phone

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, adb

I made a simple Android project in **Android Studio** ,using **Blank Activity** as my template.The Designer view can be see in the ***"Original"*** and as you can see,the title of the project is not there.
When I made the project,I used the title "Button",but is not there.
I used Genymotion to make a virtual machine,the same device used in Android Studio, Nexus 5 with android 6.0 and the result is displayed in **"Emulator"**, where there is the title.
I used the latest version of Android Studio and I did not do any modification,after the program generated all the code.

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEqZf.png)

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxu1I.png)

**EDIT**

I do not know xml that good,so I put here every piece of xml found

### **content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.bogdan.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### **strings.xml**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

### **styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"  parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

### **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.bogdan.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 1):

According to:

> What you are facing is a bug related to the API 22(5.1) SDK.
>
> Kindly refer the following links for the details on the bug in which
> the Action Bar is not displayed:
>
> 1. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159793
> 2. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159780
>
> **What you can do for now**
>
> 1. Either revert back to API 21 if possible or,
> 2. Select API 21 in the compile with (render with) option in Android Studio.
>
> From: [Activity does not show title bar in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043781/activity-does-not-show-title-bar-in-android-studio)

Check if you're using already in your `build.gradle` API 22, change to 21 or 23.

Another solution: change theme like here:

[image]

Hope this help.